# Upgrading Elasticsearch DSL

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a query that looks like this (using Elasticsearch DSL v0.0.11)

```
    s = s.filter(
        'or',
        [
            F('term', hide_from_search=False),
            F('not', filter=F('exists', field='hide_from_search')),
        ]
    )
```

How would I write that using v2.x? When the `F` function has gone?

With the `Q` function somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
q = Q('bool',
      should=[
        Q('term', hide_from_search=False),
        ~Q('exists', field='hide_from_search'),
      ],
      minimum_should_match=1
)
s = Search().query(q)
```

Or even simpler like this:

```
q = (Q('term', hide_from_search=False) | ~Q('exists', field='hide_from_search'))
q.minimum_should_match = 1
s = Search().query(q)
```